# How to display the information of a web page in a wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, web

I'm a newbie in WPF applications. I want to create a application that displays the information from a web page.. For example, my application should display the stock price of a particular company using the data in a particular site.

I want to use [moneycontrol](http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/computers-software/infosys-technologies/IT) to fetch the stock price of infosys... How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 ways ways  depending on the way you want to show information..

Either you can use [WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx) to show the Website itself in that control,

But i think you are looking for extracting or **web scraping** the data from the Web Page then you can try using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse the Html and extract the required info from there

A sample code:

```
string tickerid = "Bse_Prc_tick";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(@"http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/computers-software/infosys-technologies/IT", "GET");

if(doc != null)
{
   // Fetch the stock price from the Web page
   string stockprice = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(".//*[@id='{0}']",tickerid)).InnerText;
   Console.WriteLine(stockprice);
}
```

Output:

```
2585.55
```